# How can I reflect value of one tag into another using XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Below is the format of my XML.

I am somehow able to update the value of `tag7` from code, and I want reflect the same value in `tag3` using XSD.

Other than `tag3` and `tag7` all the tags are `complexType`.

```
<tag1>
   <tag2>
      <tag3>Yes</tag3>
   </tag2>
   <tag4>
      <tag5>
         <tag6>
            <tag7>Value</tag7>
         </tag6>
      </tag5>
   </tag4>
</tag1>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is a very vague question. please make it more clear. do you want to use your XML and create another XML? if so, what is the expected input and output? what are the tools/languages you want to use?

Comment: From code i am updating tag7 of abc.xml and is there is any way to update tag3 within same xml using abc.xsd.
Basically i want to reflect value of tag7 in tag3

Comment: what @kjhughes said: if you want to update anything, XSD is not what you are looking for. you can use XSLT, or some language-specific XML API that supports XPath and lets you update the XML.

Comment: Thanks, I used xslt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSD is for ***validation***.  Given an XML document, XSD answers the question of whether the document adheres to the constraints specified by the XSD.

> I am somehow able to update the value of `tag7` from code, and I want
>   reflect the same value in `tag3` using XSD.

XSD has no concept of ***update***.  XSD 1.0 doesn't even have a way to say that the string value of one element must equal that of another.  XSD 1.1 could express such a constraint, but note that it will use it in ***validation***; it will not maintain the constraint though update.